# DBConcurrencyException MySqlCommandBuilder

Tags: c#, mysql

When modifying data inside `DataGridView`, I get the exception:

```
DBConcurrencyException: Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records
```

When I do this:

```
// myTable is the DataSource of the datagridview.
myAdapter.Update(myTable);
```

VS2010 Debugger tells me this is the `updateCommand` when trying to update:

```
UPDATE `MySchema`.`MyDatabase` 
SET `EmployeeFirstName` = @p1 
WHERE ((`ID` = @p2) AND (`EmployeePhoneNumber` = @p3) AND
       (`EmployeeFirstName` = @p4))

@p1 is Joe (new value changed in the datagridview)
@p4 is Sally (database value)
```

**Question:**

Why am I getting a `DBConcurrencyException` if the `WHERE` clause exists in the database? (There is no actual change so there isn't any concurrency violation)

Comment: This exception is ment as "this is your DataAdapter instance talking: someone else probably already did the update you attempted, that is why I'm getting 0 rows updated, when I expected X rows to be updated.".

Comment: Correct, but Sally remains Sally in the DB. I want it to be Joe. I don't get why the adapter is lying.

Comment: No it is not. If Sally remains Sally, actually no records were changed - which is what it is saying. You need to find out why no records have been changed. One possible reason is the very nature of this exception (see my previous comment). Are you sure neither your own app nor any other user/app has already changed the record at the time you issue your update call? Sorry, but without more information there is little more I can suggest.

Comment: Is your DataTable Bound to the GidView?

Comment: Solved! The problem was that (by mistake) EmployeePhoneNumber was a float, so the datagridview shows something like 1.0923E1 while in the database the value was 10923...so the WHERE clause did not exist in the database.